# Error found: “Column count doesn't match value count at row 1”

Tags: php, mysql

I think the error should be number in insert fields doesn't match the number in value, but I really cannot see what's wrong in my code. The error is "Here is the error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" which shows that it is something wrong in my insert:

```
<?

$con2=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
  }

$result2= mysqli_query($con2,"SELECT projects.*, org.orgname FROM projects left outer join org on projects.orgid = org.orgid where projects.projectid = '".$projectid."'");
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);

$con3 = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con3)

  {

  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

  }
mysql_select_db("test", $con3);
echo $row2[target];

$sql3 = "INSERT INTO projectlog
            (projectid,projectname,generaluserid,adminuserid,swdfphase,target,objective,type,projectsize,commonth,comyear,duration,detail,projectstatus,projectsatisfaction,overallcomments,projectbenefits,orgid,createtime,lastupdatetime,logcreatetime,userid)
    VALUES
        ('".$projectid."',
        '".$row2[projectname]."',
        '".$row2[generaluserid]."',
        '".$row2[adminuserid]."',
        '".$row2[swdfphase]."',
        '".$row2[target]."',
        '".$row2[objective]."',
        '".$row2[type]."',
        '".$row2[projectsize]."',
        '".$row2[commonth]."',
        '".$row2[comyear]."',
        '".$row2[duration]."',
        '".$row2[detail]."',
        '".$row2[projectstatus]."',
        '".$row2[projectsatisfaction]."',
        '".$row2[overallcomments]."',
        '".$row2[projectbenefits]."'
        '".$row2[orgid]."',
        '".$row2[createtime]."',
        '".$row2[lastupdatetime]."',
        now(),
        '".$_SESSION[myid]."')";

if (!mysql_query($sql3,$con3))

  {

  die('Here is the error: ' . mysql_error());

  }




    mysql_close($con3); 

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are missing a comma at the end of the line

```
'".$row2[projectbenefits]."'
```